# SDL, why is there a second screen?

Tags: c++, sdl

After learning the basics of c++ I decided to get quickly into graphic libraries.
I have started reading tutorials and then, just some hours ago, with all I learned I decided to write some code that would just make a window and draw something on it.

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

class images
{
public:
    SDL_Window* OneW = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* Screensurface = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* dibujito = NULL;
    int width = 600;
    int height = 400;

bool init_sdl()
{
    bool success = true;
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        success = false;
        SDL_GetError();
    }
    else
        OneW = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL File",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,width,height,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if(OneW == NULL)
        {
            SDL_GetError();
        }
        else
        {
            Screensurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(OneW);
        }
        return success;
}

bool loadmedia()
{
    bool success = true;
    dibujito = SDL_LoadBMP("Nazi.bmp");
    if(dibujito == NULL)
    {
        SDL_GetError();
    }
    return success;
}

void close()
{
    SDL_FreeSurface(dibujito);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(OneW);
    OneW = NULL;
    SDL_Quit();
}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    images project;
    project.init_sdl();
    if(!project.init_sdl())
    {
        SDL_GetError();
    }
    else
    {
        project.loadmedia();
    }
    if(!project.loadmedia())
    {
        SDL_GetError();
    }
    else
    {
        bool game_quit = false;
        SDL_Event e;
        while(!game_quit)
        {
            while(SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
            {
                if(e.type == SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    game_quit = true;
                }
            }

            SDL_BlitSurface(project.dibujito,NULL,project.Screensurface,NULL);
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(project.OneW);
        }
    }

    project.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The program works well, it does what I want but then I realized something.
This program creates a second window, the first is black and has the image but the second is just white, empty.

Why is this second window appearing?
Also, whenever I run the program and click the X button, what SDL_QUIT would be, the window does not close. Why does that happen?

Comment: `project.init_sdl();
    if(!project.init_sdl())` - you are calling it twice..

Answer (score 0):

After you make sure to only call project.init_sdl() once there should be one window and the application should close when you call project.close() like you do. The event handling should work as well.